# How to make cauliflower pizza crust without using parmesan cheese?

Tags: substitutions, pizza, parmesan, cauliflower, keto

I want to make cauliflower pizza crust for keto diet, but all the recipes I have seen on internet require a lot of parmesan cheese, which is too expensive for me.

So I want to look for a cheaper alternative of parmesan cheese to use in cauliflower pizza crust. Can someone suggest something?

---

*Following edit is mostly copied from edit suggested by @NSGod, his/her edit was already rejected by someone senior on forum, so I couldn't mark it as approved. So I am posting this little note to give credit where it is due. Thank you.*

An example recipe from https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/katie-lee/cauliflower-pizza-crust-2651381 is:

### Ingredients:

```
1 head cauliflower, stalk removed
1/2 cup shredded mozzarella
1/4 cup grated Parmesan
1/2 teaspoon dried oregano 
1/2 teaspoon kosher salt 
1/4 teaspoon garlic powder 
2 eggs, lightly beaten
```

### Directions:

In a food processor, chop cauliflower to a fine consistency. Steam cauliflower and then drain thoroughly. In a bowl, combine the cauliflower with the mozzarella, Parmesan, oregano, salt, garlic powder and eggs. Transfer to the center of the baking sheet and spread into a circle, resembling a pizza crust. Par-bake for 20 minutes @ 400 degrees F, then add toppings and bake for another 10 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Shy, please post the full recipe and method of what you are trying to make.

Comment: @GdD Thank you. Complete recipe: https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/katie-lee/cauliflower-pizza-crust-2651381

Comment: That link is a 404 page not found @Shy.

Comment: @GdD: The link works for me here in the US.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work outside the US. It would be helpful if the recipe could be written into the question.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY The only cheese easily available in my area and affordable is cheddar cheese, mozzarella cheese, burger cheese (I have noticed it doesn't melt that easily) and cottage cheese. There is one called pizza cheese but I think it is just a combination of cheddar and mozzarella.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the recipe, the parmesan cheese is included mostly for flavor, plus a little crispiness as suggested in a comment. The mozzarella and egg are what keep the base together.

Omitting the parmesan altogether should work. You can substitute any hard(er) cheese. I would also recommend breadcrumbs if cheese is too expensive, but that will probably not fit in the Keto diet.

As a final note: the recipe calls for 1/4 cup of *grated* parmesan. Given a quick search for the [density of grated parmesan](https://www.aqua-calc.com/page/density-table/substance/cheese-coma-and-blank-parmesan-coma-and-blank-grated), this comes to about 25g (less than 1 oz.) of cheese. This does not seem like a lot to me, although you might disagree.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I got my parmesan cheese little block from store of https://www.esajee.com/. It is the best store with alot of imported stuff in my city. I tried it with it but the crust was still breaking. I need a better and cheaper binding agent.

Comment: The only cheese easily available in my area and affordable is cheddar cheese, mozzarella cheese, burger cheese (I have noticed it doesn't melt that easily) and cottage cheese. There is one called pizza cheese but I think it is just a combination of cheddar and mozzarella.

Comment: @Shy I don't think the parmesan in this recipe works as a binding agent. Cauliflower crusts are inherently less sturdy than regular old wheat-based crusts. If you want to make yours less brittle, try adding more egg and/or mozzarella. You can probably substitute cheddar for the parmesan without issues.